# Installing SSL on Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I am trying to host a website on Google Cloud Platform. It was a little startling for me that no one has ever tried something this simple or even if they have tried they have not left any documentation for others to follow. Then I found some documentation on how to host a website on a LAMP stack configured on a [Compute Engine Instance](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/joomla-on-compute-engine). It was a bit difficult for me to follow but I managed to host a website, which is a Joomla! blog. I will be configuring a basic website too in the coming few days. Now I know the steps on how to configure a custom domain for the Instance however I wanted to know how can I host a website with Google managed SSL. There is some [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssl-certificates/create) on that too however it is not detailed enough for someone like me to follow. Can someone please suggest good tutorials on the same? Maybe videos, blog posts, etc.?

Note: I am not talking about LetsEncrypt, I have seen the tutorials for doing that on a Bitnami LAMP Stack running WordPress. I wanted to know the steps for more secure, Google managed SSL for the Compute Engine Instance

Comment: "I am not talking about LetsEncrypt" You're not talking about it, but it's probably your best option. What you want to do isn't possible. LE is just as secure as Google's SSL cert.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to explore the possibilities that are present. I saw an option to create Google managed SSL also, so I thought why not use them?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use Google-managed SSL certificate directly on your VM instance.

Have a look at the documentation [Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs):

> Google-managed SSL certificates are certificates that Google Cloud
>   obtains and manages for your domains, renewing them automatically.
>   These are Domain Validation (DV) certificates supporting multiple
>   hostnames in each certificate.
>
> An SSL certificate is required for certain types of Google Cloud load
>   balancers, including:
>
> - [External HTTPS load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https)
> - [SSL proxy load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl)
>
>   **Note**: Google-managed SSL certificates aren't currently supported
>     for [internal HTTPS load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal). For internal HTTPS load balancers,
>     use [self-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs).
>
> You can also use managed SSL certificates with [Google Kubernetes
>   Engine.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine)

The [documentation](http://gcloud%20compute%20ssl-certificates%20create) you found related to ability to create Google-managed certificate before creating your load balancer:

> You can create a Google-managed certificate before, during, or after
>   creating your load balancer.

via command line interface.

To use Google-managed SSL certificates for your website you could change architecture of your web resource for example to be able to use external load balancer. If you run simple LAMP server I'd recommend you to use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates or SSL certificates from other certification centers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation